# Getting the partition id of input file in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I need to know the row index of the partitions of the input file that I'm using.  I could force this in the original file by concatenating the row index to the data but I'd rather have a way of doing this in Hadoop.  I have this in my mapper...

```
String id = context.getConfiguration().get("mapreduce.task.partition");
```

But "id" is 0 in every case.  In the "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide" it mentions accessing properties like the partition id "can be accessed from the context object passed to all methods of the Mapper or Reducer".  It does not, from what I can tell, actually go into how to access this information.

I went through the documentation for the Context object and it seems like the above is the way to do it and the script does compile.  But since I'm getting 0 for every value, I'm not sure if I'm actually using the right thing and I'm unable to find any detail online that could help in figuring this out.

Code used to test...

```
public class Test {

public static class TestMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String id = context.getConfiguration().get("mapreduce.task.partition");
        context.write(new Text("Test"), new Text(id + "_" + value.toString()));
    }
}


public static class TestReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for(Text value : values) {
            context.write(key, value);
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if(args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: Test <input path> <output path>");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(Test.class);
    job.setJobName("Test");

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(TestMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(TestReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what `row index of the partitions of the input file` actually means. Could you clarify?

Comment: @BinaryNerd I could be wrong but I thought it would be the row id of the input file.  So say if there are 100 lines in the file, I was hoping to know what the current line is that the mapper is working on (so a number from 0-99 or 1-100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options are:

1. Use the offset instead of the row number
2. Track the line number in the mapper

For the first one, the key which is `LongWritable` tells you the offset of the line being processed. Unless your lines are exactly the same length, you won't be able to calculate the line number from an offset, but it does allow you to determine ordering if thats useful.

The second option is to just track it in the mapper. You could change your code to something like:

```
public static class TestMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private long currentLineNum = 0;
    private Text test = new Text("Test");   

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
                          throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        context.write(test, new Text(currentLineNum + "_" + value));
        currentLineNum++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  I can maybe use the offset.  I see that it's multiples of 6 and yeah the lines should be the same length.  For what you provided above, how would it know what the current line is?  My assumption is that the mappers are working simultaneously so the counter in the above may not have the right number for the line.  For example, if the first mapper to finish is the one with line 5, won't it have current line number as 1?

Comment: Each instance of a mapper will sequentially process the lines in the file/split its working on. If you have multiple mappers running, they will each be processing their own split. There is no concurrent access to the files occurring, thus you can track the line using the simple method outlined above. You would need to make sure your inputs aren't splitting, so use something like gz compression.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you very much.  I thought it would be concurrent so the variable would be off but just tested it on a large dataset and works exactly as you mention.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could also represent your matrix as lines of tuples and include the row and col on every tuple so when you're reading in the file, you have that information. If you use a file that is just space or comma seperated values that make up a 2D array, it'll be extremely hard to figure out what line (row) you are currently working on in the mapper